# Azure B2C vs Azure External Identities

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have the below use-case scenarios-

Use-Case1-

I am running an online food business website which is hosted on GCP, customers will login/signup to order the food.I want to have Azure AD to manage my authentication and authorisation.

Use-Case2-

I have couple of franchises for my business and their customers I want them to manage the authentication part and I will manage authorisation part. I want to manage all such franchises using my Azure AD and logically group them. Which specific Azure AD should I go with among the following Azure AD, Azure B2C, Azure B2B, External Identities.

Use-Case3-

I have couple of franchises for my business and their customers both authentication authorisation part. I want to manage all such franchises using my Azure AD and logically group them. Which specific Azure AD should I go with among the following Azure AD, Azure B2C, Azure B2B, External Identities.

Answer (score 1):

**Azure AD B2C** is intended for  customers of your  product  whereas **Azure  B2B Collaboration** is intended for  collaborating with business partners from external organizations like partners, vendors, suppliers

> Use-Case1: I am running an online food business website which is
> hosted on GCP, customers will login/signup to order the food. I want
> to have Azure AD to manage my authentication and authorization.

In this scenario, you can use Azure AD B2C to authenticate and authorize your customers

> Use-Case2:
>
> I have couple of franchises for my business and their customers I want
> them to manage the authentication part and I will manage authorization
> part. I want to manage all such franchises using my Azure AD and
> logically group them. Which specific Azure AD should I go with among
> the following Azure AD, Azure B2C, Azure B2B, External Identities.

In this scenario, to manage the franchises and logically group them, you can use Azure AD B2B Collaboration

> Use-Case3:
>
> I have couple of franchises for my business and their customers both
> authentication authorization part. I want to manage all such
> franchises using my Azure AD and logically group them. Which specific
> Azure AD should I go with among the following Azure AD, Azure B2C,
> Azure B2B, External Identities.

In this scenario, to manage the franchises and logically group them, you use Azure AD B2B Collaboration. For customers, you can use Azure AD B2C

You can refer this use-case provided by Microsoft for more info:

[Azure Active Directory B2C Overview Example WoodGrove Groceries | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview#example-woodgrove-groceries)